# Java casting: can you force a cast to a interface if it's not declared in the to be casted class?

Tags: java, casting

I guess it's not possible, but I was wondering:

Can you cast a Class that conforms to a specific interface method-wise (but not using "implements interface") to that interface?

Any workarounds? I want to use a wrapper class for a certain class but have no access to it's constructor, and have no way to modify the receiving code that expects that class.

-edit-
Sorry, I wasn't clear about the interface. Actually those where two lines of thought merged in to a single question. I should have asked about casting a class to another class.

Comment: no you can't cast an object to an interface it does not explicitly implement

Comment: "I want to use a wrapper class for a certain class but have no access to it's constructor, and have no way to modify the receiving code that expects that class." <-- where does the interface come into play here? Does the receiving code use it?

Comment: However, you can often derive class B from class A, where B does implement the interface. It can be referenced through a type A variable or expression, but cast to the interface type. If A implements all the methods in the interface, B does not need any code.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan I was thinking that same thing, until OP indicated there was no access to the constructor :(

Comment: Keep in mind that if a field or method is `protected` you can access it from methods of a subclass.  So subclassing the class in question can sometimes get you around `protected`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer is no.  How could the system possibly know?  It would be coincidental at best.

Now in terms of a workaround, reflection is your friend here.  [Oracle tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/class/classNew.html)

Example code:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.lang.reflect.Member;
import static java.lang.System.out;

enum ClassMember { CONSTRUCTOR, FIELD, METHOD, CLASS, ALL }

public class ClassSpy {
    public static void main(String... args) {
    try {
        Class<?> c = Class.forName(args[0]);
        out.format("Class:%n  %s%n%n", c.getCanonicalName());

        Package p = c.getPackage();
        out.format("Package:%n  %s%n%n",
               (p != null ? p.getName() : "-- No Package --"));

        for (int i = 1; i < args.length; i++) {
        switch (ClassMember.valueOf(args[i])) {
        case CONSTRUCTOR:
            printMembers(c.getConstructors(), "Constructor");
            break;
        case FIELD:
            printMembers(c.getFields(), "Fields");
            break;
        case METHOD:
            printMembers(c.getMethods(), "Methods");
            break;
        case CLASS:
            printClasses(c);
            break;
        case ALL:
            printMembers(c.getConstructors(), "Constuctors");
            printMembers(c.getFields(), "Fields");
            printMembers(c.getMethods(), "Methods");
            printClasses(c);
            break;
        default:
            assert false;
        }
        }

        // production code should handle these exceptions more gracefully
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException x) {
        x.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, it should be noted that `c.getConstructors()` returns nothing and `c.getDeclaredConstructors()` does.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't, as the other posters already answered.

For the (ugly) workaround:
You can use `java.lang.Reflection`, to access any Constructor, even a private one.

Example to instantiate an object  via an private no-arg Constructor by reflection:

```
java.lang.reflect.Constructor[] c = clazz.getDeclaredConstructors();
c[0].setAccessible(true);
Object instance = c[0].newInstance(new Object[] {});
```

But be warned, once in my life a saw a VM which was configured (via SecurityManager) such that accessing private fields via reflection does not work.

Comment: Still, this probably doesn't allow me to subclass it?

Comment: Hm I dont know, i dont lik emuch subclassing. Try to use aggregation  (field with the class)

Comment: All VM's should be configured with SecurityManager imo

Answer (score 0):

You cannot cast an object reference to a class that is not in the inheritance chain of the object, nor can you cast to an interface that the object does not implement.  There is a runtime check that occurs to prevent this.

(And when it comes to casting arrays of references it gets even more restrictive.)

Answer (score 0):

No, but you can solve this issue using the Adapter design patter. Create a class that implements the interface and takes an instance of the class in question as a constructor parameter. Then just delegate all methods to this instance.